# How to copy text together with the line numbers using Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, copy-paste

I would like to copy text but with the line numbers in front. How to do it?
I would like to paste that text after that, with the line numbers in front.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Install [**Copy With Line Numbers Reloaded**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CopyWithLineNumbersReloaded)
- Select the text you want to copy
- Run `Edit: Copy With Line Numbers` from the `Command Palette`
- `Paste` @ your target document & your code will now have line numbers