# Sublime text 3 - React & FlowType syntax support, white syntax after type definition

Tags: reactjs, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, flowtype

Anybody has this issue before? I do not know how to explain so please see the picture here:

[image]

Thank you so much for your time and your help!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: @BSMP I'm curious, why? :)

Comment: @OlegsJeremejevs - Not all users will be able to see the image, it prevents anyone from being able to copy/paste the text, and it hides the text from search engines which makes it harder for someone with a similar issue to find the question.

Comment: @BSMP Did you read the question? This is a syntax highlighting issue, which is much easier and reliable to communicate with an image than [by other means](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21037711/242684).

Answer (score 1):

Install Babel for your sublime

http://www.storybench.org/install-babel-packages-sublime-text-3/

Answer (score 1):

Also had this problem for some time. Tried all kind of sublime plugins with custom syntax but non worked.

Finally found [this](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime/issues/293#issuecomment-280020907) on [babel-sublime](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime)'s git.

In a nutshell:

- get the [syntax definition from VSCode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/javascript/syntaxes/JavaScript.tmLanguage.json) which has support for Typescript, JSX, Flow
- convert it to YAML using [PackageDev](https://github.com/SublimeText/PackageDev#editing-existing-syntax-definitions)
- copy the new file(eg. `JavaScript (VSCode).tmLanguage`) to Sublime Text's User folder

You should now see the new syntax in the Command Palette.

Mine looks like this: [React/Typescript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drlSJ.png), [Flow Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4szIc.png)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

add some packages for sublime like below link, as there is no direct support react syntax:

```
https://github.com/facebookarchive/sublime-react
```

or check this [link](https://medium.com/@adrianli/setting-up-sublime-text-3-for-reactjs-3bf6baceb73a)

Comment: Sorry, i think you not get the question meaning :) Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can now simply install the Naomi package:

https://github.com/borela/naomi

All in one package, you get support for:

- CSS 3+;
- JavaScript;

  - Stage 0-3 proposals;
  - Node globals;
  - Jest globals;
  - Flow;
  - JSX with complete support for Emmet;
- HTML 5+;
- MQL4 (Updating);
- Jest Snapshot;
- PHP 7+ (Updating);
- SCSS (Updating);

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and found that it works if you put a semicolon after your closing bracket of the type definition.